# Bash: Linking I/O of two processes

Tags: bash, process, fifo

I have two programs A and B (in my case a C program and a Java program) that are supposed communicate with each other. The invocation inside a bash script of those programs looks like this:

```
mkfifo fifo1
mkfifo fifo2

A < fifo1 > fifo2 &
java B < fifo2 > fifo1
```

I know that I could do it with one fifo, but I also want to be able to show the communication on the console. The following works fine:

```
mkfifo fifo1
mkfifo fifo2

A < fifo1 | tee fifo2 &
java B < fifo2 | tee fifo1
```

My question is: Why does the second script work while the first one just hangs?

Side question: While the second version works, as soon as I redirect the output of the script to a file, the communication is no longer interleaved but ordered by process. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Is the I/O of A and B synchronous?  Or, to put it a different way, when A and B start, which one is waiting for output (they can't both be, otherwise you would have a livelock).

Comment: B will start generating output, A will await input. The input/output of the processes matches each other, that is, B is waiting exactly for what A is writing. After A has finished B will generate output which A is in turn waiting for, and so on (until some terminating condition ends B after which A will read the remaining output of B and also exit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the second script work while the first one just hangs?

[man open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):

> When opening a FIFO with O_RDONLY or O_WRONLY set:
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is set, an *open*() for reading-only
>   shall return without delay. An *open*() for writing-only shall
>   return an error if no process currently has the file open for
>   reading.
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is clear, an *open*() for reading-only
>   shall block the calling thread until a thread opens the file for
>   writing. An *open*() for writing-only shall block the calling
>   thread until a thread opens the file for reading.

In the first script, `A` opens `fifo1` and `B` opens `fifo2`, both with O_RDONLY; `A` blocks until `B` would open `fifo1` for writing, while `B` blocks until `A` would open `fifo2` for writing… a circular wait situation. (Actually, shells open the fifos, but the resulting circular waiting is the same.)

In the second script, `A` opens `fifo1` and `B` opens `fifo2`, both with O_RDONLY - so far the same as above. But in parallel, the first `tee` opens `fifo2` and the second `tee` opens `fifo1` for writing, thus unblocking `A` and `B`.

> While the second version works, as soon as I redirect the output of
>   the script to a file, the communication is no longer interleaved but
>   ordered by process. Is there a way to prevent this?

This may be due to stdout buffering; try `… stdbuf -oL tee …` or post your input and output.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will mark this as the answer.